# Android application crashes on one device but runs fine on another (identical) device?

Tags: android

looking for an answer to this problem. I'm coding a simple multiplayer game, and I have been trying to test it on two devices to see if they communicate. However, it crashes on the second device, despite it being the exact same as the first device.

Here's what the logs have been saying:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.anna.pokerapp, PID: 29964
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient must be connected.
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.games.Games.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.games.Games.zzi(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.RealTimeMultiplayerImpl.getSelectOpponentsIntent(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.anna.pokerapp.QuickGame.onStartMatchClicked(QuickGame.java:50)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

It says there's a problem with googleapiclient but if it works fine on the first device, is there something else I'm overlooking? Is it linked with the first device or something? Is that a thing?

This is the activity in question. It runs on one device but crashes on another:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.WindowManager;

    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
    import com.google.android.gms.games.GamesActivityResultCodes;
    import com.google.android.gms.games.GamesStatusCodes;
    import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Invitation;
    import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Multiplayer;
    import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.OnInvitationReceivedListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Participant;
    import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RealTimeMessage;
    import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RealTimeMessageReceivedListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.Room;
    import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RoomConfig;
    import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RoomStatusUpdateListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RoomUpdateListener;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class QuickGame extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, RoomUpdateListener, RealTimeMessageReceivedListener, RoomStatusUpdateListener {

        // Variable declarations here
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        final static int RC_SELECT_PLAYERS = 10000;
        final static int RC_WAITING_ROOM = 10001;
        boolean mPlaying = false;

        // at least 1 players required for our game
        final static int MIN_PLAYERS = 2;
        private String mRoomId = "PokerApp102";
        private Room mRoom;
        boolean mWaitingRoomFinishedFromCode = false;
        private OnInvitationReceivedListener mListener;
        private String TAG = "Chips-in";
        private final ArrayList<Participant> mParticipants = new ArrayList<Participant>(2);

        public void onStartMatchClicked(View view) {
            Intent intent = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent(mGoogleApiClient, 1, 2);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_quick_game);
            //connect googleapi
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

           // startQuickGame();
        }


        // returns whether there are enough players to start the game - in this case 2
        boolean shouldStartGame(Room room) {
            int connectedPlayers = 0;
            for (Participant p : room.getParticipants()) {
                if (p.isConnectedToRoom()) ++connectedPlayers;
            }
            return connectedPlayers >= MIN_PLAYERS;
        }

        // Returns whether the room is in a state where the game should be cancelled.
        boolean shouldCancelGame(Room room) {
            mRoomId = room.getRoomId();
            mRoom = room;
            return false;
        }

        private void startQuickGame() {
            // auto-matches specified range of players
            Bundle am = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 2, 0);
            // Room configuration
            RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
            roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(am);
            RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();
            // Create RTM room
            Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(mGoogleApiClient, roomConfig);
            // Screen stays on during handshake!
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            // go to game screen

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
            if (request == RC_SELECT_PLAYERS) {
                if (response == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // get the invitee list
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    final ArrayList<String> invitees =
                            data.getStringArrayListExtra(Games.EXTRA_PLAYER_IDS);

                    // get auto-match criteria
                    Bundle autoMatchCriteria = null;
                    int minAutoMatchPlayers =
                            data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MIN_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
                    int maxAutoMatchPlayers =
                            data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MAX_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);

                    if (minAutoMatchPlayers > 0) {
                        autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(
                                minAutoMatchPlayers, maxAutoMatchPlayers, 0);
                    } else {
                        autoMatchCriteria = null;
                    }

                    // create the room and specify a variant if appropriate
                    RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
                    roomConfigBuilder.addPlayersToInvite(invitees);
                    if (autoMatchCriteria != null) {
                        roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
                    }
                    RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();
                    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(mGoogleApiClient, roomConfig);

                    // prevent screen from sleeping during handshake
                    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                }
                else if (response == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // back button pressed - leave room
                    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(mGoogleApiClient, null, mRoomId);
                    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                }
                else if (response == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_LEFT_ROOM) {
                    // player wants to leave the room.
                    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(mGoogleApiClient, null, mRoomId);
                    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                }
            }
        }

        private RoomConfig.Builder makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder() {
            return RoomConfig.builder(this).setMessageReceivedListener(this).setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
        }

        public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

            if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
                Log.d(TAG, "GoogleAPIClient connected");
            }
            else{
                Log.d(TAG, "GoogleAPIClient not connected");
            }

            if (connectionHint != null) {
                Invitation inv = connectionHint.getParcelable(Multiplayer.EXTRA_INVITATION);

                if (inv != null) {
                    // accept invitation
                    RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
                    roomConfigBuilder.setInvitationIdToAccept(inv.getInvitationId());
                    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.join(mGoogleApiClient, roomConfigBuilder.build());

                    // prevent screen from sleeping during handshake
                    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

                    // go to game screen
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended() called. Trying to reconnect.");
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        // RoomUpdateListener methods:
        // this three methods overridden
        @Override
        public void onRoomCreated(int statusCode, Room room) {
            if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
                // let screen go to sleep
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

                // show error message, return to main screen.
                Log.d(TAG, "Room was not created successfully");
                return;
            }
            // get waiting room intent
            Intent i = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent(mGoogleApiClient, room, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            startActivityForResult(i, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
            Log.d(TAG, "Room created successfully");
        }

        @Override
        public void onJoinedRoom(int statusCode, Room room) {
            if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Joined room");
                // let screen go to sleep
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

                // show error message, return to main screen.

                return;
            }
            // get waiting room intent
            Intent i = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent(mGoogleApiClient, room, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            startActivityForResult(i, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRoomConnected(int statusCode, Room room) {
            if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
                // let screen go to sleep
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

                // show error message, return to main screen.
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected to room");
        }

        // Players Connected overridden methods
        @Override
        public void onPeersConnected(Room room, List<String> peers) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Peer connected");
            if (mPlaying) {
                // add new player to an ongoing game
            } else if (shouldStartGame(room)) {
                // start game!
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPeersDisconnected(Room room, List<String> peers) {
            if (mPlaying) {
                // do game-specific handling of this -- remove player's avatar
                // from the screen, etc. If not enough players are left for
                // the game to go on, end the game and leave the room.
            } else if (shouldCancelGame(room)) {
                // cancel the game
                Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(mGoogleApiClient, null, mRoomId);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPeerLeft(Room room, List<String> peers) {
            // peer left -- see if game should be canceled
            if (!mPlaying && shouldCancelGame(room)) {
                Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(mGoogleApiClient, null, mRoomId);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPeerDeclined(Room room, List<String> peers) {
            // peer declined invitation -- see if game should be canceled
            if (!mPlaying && shouldCancelGame(room)) {
                Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(mGoogleApiClient, null, mRoomId);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLeftRoom(int statusCode, String roomId) {
            // we have left the room; return to main screen.
            Log.d(TAG, "onLeftRoom, code " + statusCode);
            switchToMainScreen();
        }

        private void switchToMainScreen() {

        }

        private void updateRoom(Room room) {
            if (room == null) {
                return;
            }

            mParticipants.clear();
            mParticipants.addAll(room.getParticipants());
        }

        // RealTimeMessage methods
        // this method's code source: https://github.com/markushi/lib-playutils/blob/master/src/main/java/at/markushi/multiplayer/MultiPlayerHelper.java
        @Override
        public void onRealTimeMessageReceived(RealTimeMessage rtm) {
            final byte[] buf = rtm.getMessageData();
            final String sender = rtm.getSenderParticipantId();
            Log.d(TAG, "Message received from: " + sender);

            Participant participant = null;
            for (Participant p : mParticipants) {
                if (p.getParticipantId().equals(sender)) {
                    participant = p;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (participant == null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Received message from unknown participant -> discarding");
            }
        }

        // RoomStatusUpdateListenerMethods
        @Override
        public void onRoomConnecting(Room room) {
            updateRoom(room);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRoomAutoMatching(Room room) {
            updateRoom(room);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPeerInvitedToRoom(Room room, List<String> list) {
            updateRoom(room);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPeerJoined(Room room, List<String> list) {
            updateRoom(room);
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectedToRoom(Room room) {
          /*  Log.d(TAG, "onConnectedToRoom.");
            roomId = room.getRoomId();
            mParticipants.clear();
            mParticipants.addAll(room.getParticipants());
            userId = room.getParticipantId(Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId(gameHelper.getApiClient()));*/
        }

        // overridden code
        @Override
        public void onDisconnectedFromRoom(Room room) {
            // leave the room
            Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(mGoogleApiClient, null, mRoomId);

            // clear the flag that keeps the screen on
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            // show error message and return to main screen
        }

        @Override
        public void onP2PConnected(String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onP2PDisconnected(String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        }
    }
```

Any advice? Will post more if requested. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I encounter errors for an Android application running on one device and not on other I usually do the checks that the others have suggested above.

And then I also check the OS version of the devices if they are the same. If not I will check the version on the device where it generates errors and see if it is compatible with and API - in this case the GMS API. If this is the case, you should probably do some more adjustments to the code so that it will run on different OS versions.

Lastly, based on the error logs it says "GoogleApiClient must be connected". Based on the GoogleApiClient [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient) before any operation is executed, the connection must be checked. And to manage the connection is to use enableAutoManage. I see in your code above that this is not set-up in the builder. You can probably try adding it like this:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .build();
```

Where: *enableAutoManage(FragmentActivity, OnConnectionFailedListener)*

Code from [this site](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client).

And if you still encounter the IllegalStateException error, the documentation also says that

*"if another GoogleApiClient is already being auto-managed with the default clientId."*

So might want to check that as well.

Comment: .enableAutoManage(this, this) worked! Thank you so much!! <3

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Google Play Services is up to date, or is the same in both versions.

1. Go to Settings
2. open Apps
3. find Google Play Services, and update it.

Comment: Just checked; both are up-to-date :/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a problem with your application connecting to Google Play Services, especially Google Play Games.

Check whether Google Play Games is installed on the device you're facing errors on. If yes, try updating Google Play Games to the most recent version.

Comment: Google Play Games is installed and up-to-date, according to my device